# Is gun oil worth the cost for oiling an axe compared to alternatives?

Tags: tools

I've done some research on axe maintenance and it seems gun oil is the best lubricant for axes. However [at approximately $10 for a 4oz. bottle](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_2_7?field-keywords=gun+oil&url=search-alias%3Dsporting&x=0&y=0&sprefix=gun+oil) cost becomes an issue if you get a lot of use out of your axe and oil it after ever day of use. Is a cheaper alternative like 5w-30 motor oil adequate?

I will note that [if its ok to spraypaint my axe head](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8917/is-it-a-good-idea-to-spraypaint-my-axe-head), then the cost of using gunoil becomes cheaper since I don't need to oil the entire surface.

Comment: It might be worth combining both your questions into one, as they are both about ways to protect and preserve your axe when not in use.

Comment: Why oil an axe I wonder?

Comment: Same reason yoou'd oil any sort of metal cutting instrument. To protect it from rust and the like. You oil pocket knives.

Comment: @Justin Dearing: Actually I don't - I just buy ones made of stainless steel and that's all. But practically how will oiling persist on the surface and not stain stuff around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say almost any synthetic oil would work. I know people that use Mobile 1 Synthetic on their rifles.

Comment: I'm going with Mobile1